# hadoop dfs -ls complains

Tags: hadoop, ls

Can anyone let me know what seems to be wrong here ? hadoop dfs command seems to be OK but any following options are not recognized.

`[hadoop-0.20]$bin/hadoop dfs -ls ~/wordcount/input/
ls: Cannot access /home/cloudera/wordcount/input/ : No such file or directory`

Comment: it also shows the same message when I use bin/hadoop dfs namemode -format : could not find the main class: namemode

Answer (score 13, accepted):

hadoop fs -ls /some/path/here - will list a HDFS location, not your local linux location
try first this command

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

then investigate step by step other folders.

if you want to copy some files from local directory to users directory on HDFS location, then just use this:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /users
hadoop fs -put /some/local/file /users
```

for more hdfs commands see this: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/hdfs_shell.html

Answer (score 0):

FS relates to a generic file system which can point to any file systems like local, HDFS, s3 etc But dfs is very specific to HDFS. So when we use FS it can perform operation with from/to local or hadoop distributed file system to destination. But specifying DFS operation relates to HDFS.